# What is the maximum size of an vector<>::maxsize()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

Please specify the range of vector list ....

I want to store million of records in vector<>.

I have to copy Millions of records from one vector<> to another vector<> and then sort the vector and apply my filter function(unique id) to retrieve the record.

is this possible in vector

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: The answer depends on what you are storing. You should be able to calculate this for yourself - determine the size of the object you are storing in the vector, then multiply by the number of them you require, and that should give you a rough idea... And please - refer to the docs, you've asked some really basic questions (and there's nothing wrong with asking) that could be answered by looking at the docs...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the maximum size of an vector ....

I think you have answered your own question.
Theoretical limit for your system you can get with a function `vector<T>::max_size()`. For instance:

```
vector<int> vec;
std::cout<<vec.max_size()<<std::endl;//prints max size for vector<int> in your system!
```

So just run this and check out the answer for your system.

However in practice the vector's allocated array must be in one consecutive memory block and even with less size memory allocation can fail. If you are going to use vector of ints with million elements I think you shouldn't have any problems. However for bigger objects it can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit except the available memory. But: a vector requires all the memory to be in one consecutive memory area. If you want to store a million records, there might not be such a big memory area available.

In that case, it's better to use a `deque` instead of a `vector`.

Comment: A million records isn't that much. Could be 100 MB perhaps? And I'm sure karthik has a server with 16 GB RAM. :-)

Comment: `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/max_size/` `vector<T>::max_size()` returns maximal theoretical size (due to implementation and system limitations. so your answer is not comletly correct.

Comment: @karthik - Then you have nothing to worry about, unless you work with a small embedded system (unlikely).

Comment: @BOPersson: But my problem is happened only on RAM size.Is any otherway to overcome this issue

Answer (score -2):

I test it in my pc. Windows 7 32bit.
The result is `2^32/sizeof(CPoint3D)-1=268435455`, `sizeof(CPoint3D)` is 16. 
But `max_size` is nothing. After it, `m_point1.reserve(25641355)`, "Out of Memory" is showed.

`25641355 < 268435455`

Comment: This answer is so specific to one machine, compiler, and runtime that - even if you had bothered to tell us how much RAM it has, how much was free, and which compiler you used - it still does not reflect the real answer i.e. what the standard says, and it isn't a practical answer for the ~100% of users who don't have exactly the same PC and setup. Only what the Standard says is of any use, not individuals' anecdotes.