# How much data can a vector<string> hold?

Tags: c++, csv, memory, vector

I have a program that generates a .csv file by fetching data from two separate .csv files.

I have used a `vector<string>` to hold data from each csv file then my program does data sorting based on certain conditions and thus generates an output. I fear  my program might run out of memory.

How much data can a `vector<string>` hold at a time ?? Is it system/processor/OS specific ??

Comment: Maybe you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469123/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-vectormaxsize) out

Comment: how big are the .csv files??

Comment: the csv files might have 1000+ input

Comment: vector<string> or any other container for that matter...it will hold as much data as allowed by OS unless vector itself has a self imposed limit..just handle any exception thrown by vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with `vector<T>::max_size()` which is very large number, from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/) you can read its 1073741823 on the system where this example was run. But I suppose you are more interested in real world scenerio - here you will get bad_alloc exception when there will bo no consecutive memory block available on your process heap. One solution might be to use [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) - which will it doing allocations in chunks.

Comment: vector<T>::max_size() is very unlikely to be useful.  It will probably be close to SIZE_MAX/sizeof(T), but it doesn't account for the data actually in the strings, and it doesn't account for other memory usages.  All you can say about max_size, is that you can't make the vector *bigger* than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is system/processor/OS specific.

For a 32-bit program it is likely to be limited to 2GB (and if you have any other data, it will be less).  A 64-bit program will probably be limited by available swap space (so several GB).

Embedded systems will offer less (possibly very much less).

A few 10s or 100s of MB should be no problem though.